After 'cargo install wasm-pack' do I need to manually update chrome & chromedriver?
I'm on Windows 11. When I cargo install wasm-pack it installs chromedriver v 114, but v 114 doesn't work with the current version of Chrome.
I want to be able to run tests via wasm-pack test --chrome --headless.
As a workaround, I downloaded Chrome and chromedriver from Chrome for Testing. I then put the Chrome for Testing version of Chrome on my path and replace the chromedriver.exe that wasm-pack installed.
Is there any better alternative than this workaround or this this "best practices"?

Does it say "Cannot load or fetch chromedriver's latest version data..."?
